# Notifications won't open when I click on them on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, notifications, action-center

I get my notifications on my *Action Center* on Windows 10.
When I click on them to get to their website to actually read the notification, it just disappears and it won't take me to the website.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I am having this same issue but with ANY notification from the Action Centre. Clicking on them simply closes it and nothing happens. So annoying. They only work if I open the Action Centre and click on them from there. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @RajParmar What version of Windows are you running and did you try @drmoishe-pippik's answer below?  If your Windows version isn't >=v1903, updating will likely solve the issue, otherwise try the following commnds in the order listed: `dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup` > `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` > reboot > `sfc /scannow` > reboot.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10, there are a number of different dialogs that control notifications.
[image: Notifications & actions dlg]

- In *Settings* | *Notifications & actions*, you may need to turn on `Get notifications from apps and other senders`, as well as the switch for a specific sender.

[image: Background apps]

- In *Settings* | *Privacy* | *Background apps*, you may need to turn on `Let apps run in the background`, and select specific apps to display its notifications. (This requirement may be new to Windows 10 v. 1809; I noticed after installation  that *Notifications* was broken until background apps were enabled.)

And, as T. Lehrer said of the elements, "There may be many other [dialogs] but they haven't been discahvahd."

Comment: This answer doesn’t seems to solve the OP’s problem. It doesn’t make sense, apps running in background can have nothing related to notifications not opening.

Comment: @Valay_17, Notifications *is* an app. It needs to run in the background. It may not make sense to you, but try turning that off and see what happens.

Comment: Ohk, now I understood what you meant, sorry my bad.

Comment: Seems not working for me.

Comment: The same thing is now happening in Windows 11; and these instructions don;t apply; anybody figured it out?